# Resetting of numbering of Section and Subsection in each Chapter

Tags: sectioning

I want to reset the numbering of Section and Subsection, Figures and Equation in each chapter.

At present the numbering is given below :

Chapter No 1:

1.1 Section 1

1.2 Section 2

1.2.1   Subsection

And so on

Chapter No 2

```
2.1 Section 1

2.2 Section 2
```

And so on.

But I want in the following format

Chapter No 1:

1.1 Section 1,

1.2 Section 2,

1.2.1   Subsection,

And so on,

Chapter No 2,

```
1.1  Section 1,

1.2 Section 2,
```

And so on. ,

Can you please guide me how can I implement it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I beg your pardon, but what would the first  1 in section numbers for chapter 2 refer to?

Comment: That will be very confusing for your readers and an annoying burden to make cross references between chapters because you have to maually add a reference to the chapter when referring from outside the chapter.

Comment: Even if you decide to do this, isn't the first `1.` redundant? Why not just use "1. Section 1", "2. Section 2", etc.? (If you go ahead, you can do what you want by redefining `\thesection` like this: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\thesection{1.\@arabic\c@section}\makeatother`)

Comment: Dear David: Many thanks for your kind response. Your suggestion solve my problem. In my document every chapter is independent therefore there will be no cross referencing. However can you please guide me that how can I do "1. Section 1", "2. Section 2" for each chapter.

Comment: Dear Bernard: Thanks for your reply. Section 1.1 means 1st section of the chapter, 1.2 means second section of the chapter and so on..